# NEST API - IOS Code Example

Tags: nest-api

Can anyone divulge the absolute steps and technology to make Nest API calls from an IOS app .to be honest I am new to this arena and i am stuck in many angles .

I am new to programming and IOS ..any help will be greatly appreciated. I dont need links I need the 9 yards

Comment: So no links… that means you have already read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-quickstart.html and https://developer.nest.com/documentation/nest-api-intro  Can you be more specific about which parts you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

We've added sample code for iOS over [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/ios-nestdk). Have a look and let us know if you have any further questions!

Cheers,
Raymond

Comment: is there any danger in including the client-secret in a published ios app?